# Graphing coordinates in Calc using direction, distance, and speed

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

Suppose I have the following data:

| Location | Direction (Degrees) | Distance | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Origin | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| A | 090 | 5 | 50 |
| B | 180 | 15 | 75 |

I can make a chart using the following data to show the path something takes:

| Location | X | Y | East | West |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Origin |  |  | 0 | 0 |
| A | D*SIN(DEG) | D*COS(DEG) | D1+B2 | E1+C2 |
| B | D*SIN(DEG) | D*COS(DEG) | D2+B3 | E2+C3 |

If I know my speed on each leg of the journey, and a start time from the origin (for the sake of simplicity, assume start time = cell A1), am I able to plot a single point using a `=NOW()-A1` formula for elapsed time to show where on the lines of a chart I'm expected to be?